# slow speed of google app engine search API

Tags: google-app-engine, full-text-search, search-engine

I have put in about 16000 products on google app engine search index.
The search operation seems to be very slow now.On a lot of occassions,I get timeout error exception(deadline exceeded exception).It is not possible for me to migrate the entire database now.Kindly provide me some means to fasten up the search results.

Comment: How can we help if we don't see your code? Search API is fast - there must be a problem somewhere else.

Comment: If you can post the schema and perhaps how you intend to query it, maybe we could provide some assistance, GAE Datastore is not RDBS, in general 16000 entities is not considered as large and should be easily searched fast.

Comment: My structure includes a set of keywords which are considered as products say for category cable,the document will have the keywords cable>>armoured>>copper as a product.Another product could be cable>>armoured>>aluminium.Further,id's of multiple suppliers are also stored in the same document for any product.I get results using the normal search API provided by google but later I filter the suppliers such that one supplier shows up only once in search results.How do I further optimize to fasten up the results.Also,would going by some other search platform like ES fasten up the search?

Answer (score 0):

To increase the time needed for uploading 16000 products to Google App Engine search index, you can try following things:

- Run on VPS with very fast Internet connection (like Amazon EC)
- Separate your task to many threads
- Separate whole task to at least 2 kinds of thread: loading product and uploading product.